# How to set up a system that reads PMML files which I create using R?

Tags: java, r, tomcat, pmml

For the past few days I'm stuck at trying to pass a PMML file with .xml extension that I created using `R` and `pmml` package. After creating a `iris.xml` PMML file I have no where to go, actually I don't know what to look for. And then I saw Alex Guazzelli's video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuSaP-vwSpI), where he tells us to use ADAPA from Zementis to run the PMML files that are created from R.

What I took away from the video is,

1. I want to do something similar as shown, like uploading my PMML file at some place and input my test files frequently to get the corresponding predicted values.
2. ADAPA looks great, but looks like it also costs some money. So I would like to look for an alternative, which might not be as user friendly as ADAPA.
3. Then I found this [page](http://www.r-bloggers.com/predictive-modeling-using-r-and-the-openscoring-engine-a-pmml-approach/) where the author says,

> So the first step was to get the engine running. I experienced some small problems but Scott fixed them very fast and offered a new war file ready for deployment inside tomcat. It can be obtained under http://code.google.com/p/openscoring/. If you still encounter some problems you could also try my war file. It was built with java version “1.6.0_26” and tested under tomcat 7. After installing the war file using the management console, you could test it by sending a POST request in XML like the following to ‘http://localhost:8080/OpenScoring/Scoring’

Then I found [jpmml](https://github.com/jpmml). The problem here is the package names are very confusing, I don't know which one to install. In fact I don't know how to install each of them. I have basic knowledge of Java, apparently it isn't helpful in the current scenario.

Desperately looking forward for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

How do the data flows in your application look like? Zementis' ADAPA is a standalone web service, which lets you do scoring in a request/response fashion. This works for web applications, but is clearly sub-optimal if you're looking to score larger amounts of data.

The JPMML project provides "PMML runtimes" for most popular big data frameworks. For example, if your application is tied to Apache Spark, then you would go for the [JPMML-Spark](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-spark) project, if tied to Apache Hive/Pig, then for the [JPMML-Pig](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-piglet) project, etc. For a simple REST web service you should check out the [Openscoring](https://github.com/jpmml/openscoring) project, which is functionally identical to Zementis' ADAPA.

All JPMML projects can be built from their source checkout using [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) by issuing the following command:

```
mvn clean install
```

Some JPMML projects also have their binaries distributed via the [Maven Central repository](http://search.maven.org/). If you're looking for the Openscoring WAR file, then you need to search for "openscoring-webapp" and on the results page click the "download WAR" link (at the time of writing this, you would get `openscoring-webapp-1.2.12.war`). This is a standard WAR file that can be dropped to the auto deploy folder of your favourite Java web server (Tomcat?) as it is. The REST API of the web service is fully documented in the README file of the Openscoring project.

Comment: thanks for reaching out. As I said I have zero knowledge(of java, as I have written codes like printing "Hello world" while in graduation) but I've been trying to understand. For now, what I need is a simple workflow of what I can do to use my PMML file in local machine by using Tomcat or something. For example,
1. Install Tomcat.
2. Install openscoring from ___ etc,.
I would very much appreciate if it is much more detailed(or specify the links where its mentioned in detail). I know this is too much to ask for. Thank you so much :)

Comment: You should really try to install Apache Maven in your computer. It's basically a matter of downloading a binary release, unpacking it, and setting two environment variables (first, adding Apache Maven's executable `mvn` to your system path `$PATH` and then defining `$JAVA_HOME`). Step-by-step instructions for this are given in Maven website. After that, follow the Openscoring README file. Once you're able to execute `mvn clean install`, you will get a standalone server application, that can be started directly from command-line. It's all in the README.